# How to delete single pod in kubernetes permanently

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I want to delete single pod of kubernetes permanently but it will recreate that pod

i have tried many commands but it doesn't help me.

```
1. kubectl delete pod <pod-name>
```

2nd

```
kubectl get deployments

kubectl delete deployments <deployments- name>
```

```
kubectl get rs --all-namespaces
kubectl delete rs your_app_name
```

but None of that works

Comment: Check your deployment, you probably have replicas set to a certain value. In that case, you would have to reduce replica count

Comment: It would help to see the output of some of those commands. Without that, we really have no idea what's going on.

Comment: @Caldazar my replica count is 0

Comment: @larsks when i tried to delete pod. it will successfully delete the pod but then after it will restart.

Comment: Which Kubernetes version did you use? Please also paste to the question your yaml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`my replica count is 0`

`...it will successfully delete the pod but then after it will restart`

Try:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: ...
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never  # <-- add this
  containers:
  - name: ...
```

If the pod still restart, post output of `kubectl describe pod <pod name> --namespace <name>` to your question.

Comment: I am not able to change pod yml . and getting this error spec: Forbidden: pod updates may not change fields other than `spec.containers[*].image`, `spec.initContainers[*].image`, `spec.activeDeadlineSeconds` or `spec.tolerations`

Comment: You need to replace instead of apply: `kubectl replace -f <pod.yaml> --force`